# Only Certain UserForm Fields Mandatory While Others are "And Or" Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I hope you are all keeping safe! 
Within my UserForm, there are multiple ComboBoxs and TextBoxs. 
When the Command Button is clicked Ideally what I would like to achieve is that: *ComboBox2* & *Textbox6* are a mandatory requirement, while having *Either* *textbox2* **and or (one or the other)** *Textbox3* also a mandatory requirement, before the form copies into the workbook.
The following code makes the ComboBox2 field mandatory but I just don’t know how to make either *textbox2* and OR *Textbox3* a requirement. 
 I've just started to learn a little about Excel VBA, so any help is greatly appreciated! :)

```
If ComboBox2.Value = "" And ComboBox3.Value = "" And TextBox6.Value = "" Or TextBox16.Value = "" Or TextBox17.Value = "" Then
   MsgBox "You must select a: Category/Type, a Description, and a Start Date" & vbCrLf & "And enter either an: Expenses or Income Amount." & vbCrLf & "Please check your entries and try again.", vbCritical
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

When validating inputs on `UserForms` there are a few ways I do it.

Here is an example from an input form that requires all but 1 field to be completed:

### The userform:

[image: Add LG products example form]

### And the validation in the code behind:

```
Dim Code As String
Dim Description As String
Dim Qty As String
Dim Min As String
Dim ProductType As String
Dim Supplier As String
Dim StockMinimums As String

With Me
    Code = .txtCodeLG.Text
    Description = .txtDescriptionLG.Text
    Qty = .txtQtyLG.Value
    Min = .txtMinLG.Value

    If .chkEMG80.Value = True Then
        ProductType = .chkEMG80.Caption
    ElseIf .chkUCP100.Value = True Then
        ProductType = .chkUCP100.Caption
    ElseIf .chkEMGLicences.Value = True Then
        ProductType = .chkEMGLicences.Caption
    ElseIf .chkUCPLicences.Value = True Then
        ProductType = .chkUCPLicences.Caption
    End If

Dim opt As Control

    For Each opt In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(opt) = "OptionButton" Then
            If opt.Value = True Then
                Supplier = opt.Caption
            Else
                'Do nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next opt
End With

If Me.chkMinimumsSheet.Value = True Then
    StockMinimums = "Yes"
ElseIf Me.chkMinimumsSheet.Value = False Then
    StockMinimums = "No"
End If

'--------------------------------------Error checking-------------------------------------

Dim ErrorString As String

If Code = "" Then
    ErrorString = ErrorString + "Please enter a value into the 'Code' box." & vbNewLine
End If

If Description = "" Then
    ErrorString = ErrorString + "Please enter a value into the 'Description' box." & vbNewLine
End If

'If Qty = "" Then
'    ErrorString = ErrorString + "Please enter a value into the 'Quantity' box." & vbNewLine
'End If

If Min = "" Then
    ErrorString = ErrorString + "Please enter a value into the 'Minimum' box." & vbNewLine
End If

If ProductType = "" Then
    ErrorString = ErrorString + "Please choose a 'Product Type'." & vbNewLine
End If

If Supplier = "" Then
    ErrorString = ErrorString + "Please select a 'Supplier'." & vbNewLine
End If

If Not ErrorString = "" Then
    MsgBox ErrorString + vbNewLine & "Danger to manifold.", vbCritical, "Values Missing"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

And if the user clicks submit without filling out the required fields it displays a descriptive message advising what is missing *(heres the msgbox when nothing is filled in)*:

[image: Result of submit click with missing values - messagebox dispays]

Answer (score 0):

you can use an "or" or "and" statement like you would in non vba excel, its just a little different formatting.  But you are exactly on the right path!

Basically if both are blank, then a message would pop up requiring a value in one of the boxes.  If one or both are filled in, then good.  I.E.

```
if textbox2.value = "" and textbox3.value = "" then
   msgbox "You must enter a value in textbox 2 and/or 3", vbCritical
   exit sub
end if
```

for an "or" statement, just replace "and" with "or"

Edit to add:

for going thru multiple iterations thru your userform for data validation and checking if boxes are filled in, etc.  I would start top to bottom, and do a check for each one.

```
if textbox1.value = "" then
    msgbox "Please fill in " & textbox1.name (or .tag or some other way to identify the item), vbcritical, "Error"
    exit sub
elseif combobox2.value = "" then
    msgbox "Please fill in " & combobox2.name, vbcritical, "Error"
    exit sub
elseif textbox6.value = "" then
    msgbox "Please fill in " & textbox6.name, vbcritical, "Error"
    exit sub
elseif textbox2.value = "" or textbox3.value="" then
    msgbox "Please fill in either textbox 2 or 3", vbcritical, "Error"
    exit sub
end if
```

If they are simple, and have a way to loop as described by another gentleman, you can use a generic formula such as

```
for i=1 to 5
    if me.controls("Textbox" & i).value = "" then
       msgbox "Please fill in " & me.controls("textbox" & i).name, vbcritical, "Error"
        exit sub
        exit for
     end if
 next i
```

I would perhaps use a combination if you have a lot of boxes.  Say there are 10 mandatory boxes, I can use the loop thru all 10 mandatory, and then just use individual if then statements using the "or" statement to check those that are one or the other

Comment: Oh, that's amazing it's working to a point now! :)  Just a little stuck, maybe super obvious and I'm probably looking right. But I am unable to get the "And Or" part working. Textbox16 & 17 If one on or the other has data entered, I would love to make one of them required. Have updated my original question with the updated code. :)

Comment: I would recommend going thru each item one by one, an easy way is to start top to bottom on your userform.  I will amend my answer to describe in detail.